# Linq with Left Join using Get list

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, left-join

I am using Entity Framework with Linq using Left join. I tried many code. But getting error. My code is as follows.

```
var ABC = (from p in AgEntities.tbl_PrayerRequest 
           join u in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster
           on p.User_IndexID equals u.User_IndexID into lj 
           from s in lj.DefaultIfEmpty() 
           select new { p.RequestID, p.RequestName, p.RequestEmail, s.User_LoginID }).ToList();
```

But I am getting the below error.

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method.
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Solution.Bussines.Entities.tbl_UserMaster] DefaultIfEmpty[tbl_UserMaster](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Solution.Bussines.Entities.tbl_UserMaster])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: Why do you use .DefaultIfEmpty() on a object enumerable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ABC = (from p in AgEntities.tbl_PrayerRequest 
           join u in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster
           on p.User_IndexID equals u.User_IndexID into lj 
           from s in lj.DefaultIfEmpty() 
           select new { p.RequestID, p.RequestName, p.RequestEmail,
                 User_LoginID =s==null?0: s.User_LoginID }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment..but still getting same error.

Comment: please reply to my question

Comment: var ABC  =(from p in AgEntities.tbl_PrayerRequest.ToList()
           join u in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster
           on p.User_IndexID equals u.User_IndexID
           into lj from u in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { p.RequestID, p.RequestName,  p.RequestEmail,User_LoginID=(u==null?
           null:u.User_LoginID)}).ToList();